Route conflict with next-auth 4 and the actual API
I already have a public REST API (PHP/Nginx) which is live and already being consumed, lets call it https://example.com/api/...
Now there has to come a GUI with authentication, to manage the API resources. The GUI should be accessible through the API's main URL https://example.com. I decided to use Next.js and next-auth 4.
next-auth 4's routing uses /api/auth/* by default. This works fine locally.
Now the problem is the deployment. When I go to https://example.com, I see the UI build. As soon as I click on the login button, a route change to https://example.com/api/auth/error happens, but showing the error output of the REST API (PHP/Nginx). This behavior makes sense for now, since the Webserver is configured in that way, that all /api requests are calling the REST API entrypoint.
What I don't want is to configure the webserver in such a way, that /api/auth is ignored for calling the REST API entrypoint. Because it's not only a webserver, its in a Kubernetes cluster, and this is complicated (we are using helmfile, helmcharts, etc.).
What I would like is the ability to customize the next-auth default authentication routing.
I tried with the basePath stuff, but I just get 404 errors, until I realized (if I unterstood correctly) that this feature is anyway only for when the entire UI has to come in a subpath, which is not in my case.
Is there any way to customize the next-auth /api/auth/* path, without changing the basePath?
When I just put pages/api into pages/foo/api, obviously on a page refresh I get GET http://localhost:3000/api/auth/session 404 (Not Found), because next-auth expects the api folder to be in pages/.

As far as I know, you just need to set the NEXTAUTH_URL env to whatever you want. In your case, something like:
vercel
NEXTAUTH_URL=https://example.com/foo/api/auth 

dev
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000/foo/api/auth

This should change your requests to things like http://localhost:3000/foo/api/auth/session
Now, for the Next.JS app to answer on this URL, you would need to add a basePath with the Pages router which you seem to use. As far as I know, Pages router only allows APIs in the api folder directly under pages.
With the new App router, you can create a folder path app/foo/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts that should catch these. The good news is that you can combine both routers in the same app.

I have to prevent the auth url starting with /api. So I locally set NEXTAUTH_URL to http://localhost:3000/auth, but after devserver restart & hard reload, still next-auth tries to request a session with an URL starting with /api (http://localhost:3000/api/auth/session 404 Not Found). I would expect a request like http://localhost:3000/auth/api/auth/session, unfortunately it is not.

I edited the response to make it more complete (and correct based on the path you mentioned)

With NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000/foo/api/auth the home site still makes a http://localhost:3000/api/.. request. With basePath: "/foo" the entire app is under /foo but I want to let it work in the root. I tried using the new router in the first place a few weeks ago, failed for some reason. I guess I have to try it again. I also only now realized that pages/api with Pages Router in Next.js is treated specifically.

Do you have any configuration that might set the URL? I'm thinking something like redirect URL. Maybe in configs for OAuth clients. Could you eventually get a screenshot of the whole network chain when logging in?

For protocol: While trying to use the new router, I remember why I failed back then. How could I forget. The documentation of next-auth 4 with the new router is a total catastrophe. Consequential errors due to client vs server rendering, without end. "The easiest way to get started" cloning the example app, is not good either, it differs too much from the current tutorial setup, and it's based on next-auth@5.0.0-beta. I guess I have to use next-auth 5, which I intentionally did not want to use due to installation bugs which I already Issued and which were approved. Frustrating :-)

Might be a bit outdated but I created https://github.com/Agilxp/next-auth-server-component some time back that should probably still work

I solved it with next-auth 5 beta and app router. I give you an upvote for leading me to the right direction, I very appreciated it.

I guess it is not possible with next-auth 4 and the app router, at least this combination is not well documented.
It worked with next-auth 5 (still beta) and the app router:

Moving app/api/auth up to app/auth
Setting AUTH_URL to http://my-host/auth

